# What are legal paths for --module-path for javac?

Tags: java, javac, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

What are legal paths for `--module-path` for `javac`?

So far, I think that the following are legal (i.e. will not cause an error):

1. paths that don't exist
2. directories that do not contain an immediate child named `module-info.class` that is not a valid module descriptor class (so, a directory with a valid `module-info.class` is fine, as is a directory that does not contain a `module-info.class`)
3. paths that end with `.jar`, and whose contents are a valid zip file

Are any of the above incorrect?

Are there any other legal paths for `--module-path`?

I also think that 2 & 3 will modify the module path (i.e. create a module on the module path, subject to no errors being thrown by module validation), whereas 1 is a no-op, and anything that doesn't match 1, 2, or 3 will cause an error.

Comment: Please define "legal". Directories are acceptable in `--module-path` but the module system will not put any files in these directories into the module path.

Comment: Legal: path will not cause an error

Comment: OK, so I think your list is correct. All of these are legal paths.

Comment: If you mean what all does javac validates when the option`--module-path` is specified. I think the list is almost correct, though you can probably peep into `JavacTool` class in the JDK if I correctly remember the class name which might just help you with the detailed validations as well.

Comment: Another definition: affects module path: will actually add classes to the module path: 1. obviously doesn't affect the module path. 3. obviously does affect the module path. I think that 2. only affects the module path if the directory has an immediate child file named `module-info.class` that is a valid module descriptor; if a `module-info.class` isn't valid, then it causes an error